# How to Use WinHttpRequest (WinHTTP Services) in Excel VBA to Stream Data from Websocket Server

Tags: excel, vba, websocket, winhttp, winhttprequest

I would like to stream data from a websocket server using VBA in an Excel workbook.

This is the actual data stream I would like to receive and process in VBA:

[image: Screenshot Chrome Developer Tools]

**Would you recommend using WinHttpRequest (WinHTTP Services) or any other service to connect and receive the websocket data?**

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest) it is not clear to me if WinHttpRequest supports the websocket protcol and unfortunately no examples are presented.

Comment: WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 ActiveX doesn't expose such methods allowing to work with websockets. May be that is possible via direct calls to Winhttp.dll.